# Using lapply on a diverse list in R

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I created a list containing sub-lists, each sub-list containing information for one task I want R to do.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:6 , ncol =2 , nrow = 3))
colnames(df) <- c("Col1", "Col2")
myList <- list()
myList[["Dataset1"]] <- list()
myList[["Dataset1"]]["Function"] <- "mean" 
myList[["Dataset1"]][["DataFrame"]] <- df
myList[["Dataset2"]] <- list()
myList[["Dataset2"]]["Function"] <- "lm" 
myList[["Dataset2"]][["DataFrame"]] <- df*2
```

Now I want R to apply the Function to the Dataframe and Store the results in a new List. How do I do that best?

So far I had two ideas: I either use lapply to run through the list, each time accessing several items from the sub-list, supplying it to a new function

```
myResult <- lapply(myList, FUN = myList[["Dataset1"]]["Function"](x) , x = as.matrix(myList[["Dataset1"]][["DataFrame"]]))
```

But I dont know how to tell R how to cycle correctly through the sub-lists.

Second, I was hoping to be able to send the whole sublist to a function, but I could not get this to run either.

```
myFunction <- function(x){
  TempData <- x[["DataFrame"]]
  TempFunction <- x["Function"]
  
  TempResult <- get(TempFunction)(TempData)
  
  return(TempResult)
}

myResult <- lapply(myList, myFunction(x))
```

If someone could give me an idea how to solve this id be very happy.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you apply `mean` function to a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more complicated than it should be.. And it's not clear how you would apply mean() or lm(). Below is an example where you store the function as an object in the list:

```
myList[["Dataset1"]] <- list()
myList[["Dataset1"]][["Function"]] <- function(x)mean(as.matrix(x))
myList[["Dataset1"]][["DataFrame"]] <- df
myList[["Dataset2"]] <- list()
myList[["Dataset2"]][["Function"]] <- function(x){lm(Col2~Col1,data=x)}
myList[["Dataset2"]][["DataFrame"]] <- df*2
```

So you iterate through elements in the list and you get the result of function(dataframe) for each element:

```
lapply(myList,function(i)i$Function(i$DataFrame))
$Dataset1
[1] 3.5

$Dataset2

Call:
lm(formula = Col2 ~ Col1, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Col1  
          6            1
```

Comment: Thanks, I think storing the function in the list will help a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

A first thing you can do is use the `match.fun` function that allows you to recover a function from a string. Applied to a loop, it returns the following solution :

```
list<-list()
for (i in 1:length(myList)){
 TempFunc <- match.fun(myList[[i]][["Function"]])
 Results <- TempFunc(myList[[i]][["DataFrame"]])
 list[i]<-Results
}

> list
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
(Intercept)        Col2 
         -6           1
```

Actually, the functions don't make sense because the functions are not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about a loop but I once read that apply was faster and easier to pareallelize (for multicore usage). The functions dont make sense, the real data are a little more complex but for the sake of simpleness I just used something trivial. Sum would work on a matrix, but not a dataframe i guess. I will give match function a try!

Answer (score 1):

The function `call` allows you to call a function by its name given as a character string, and you can evaluate this call with `eval`. Note though, that neither of your function calls make sense applied to a data frame:

```
lapply(myList, function(sublist) call(sublist$Function, sublist[["DataFrame"]]))
#> $Dataset1
#> mean(list(Col1 = 1:3, Col2 = 4:6))

#> $Dataset2
#> lm(list(Col1 = c(2, 4, 6), Col2 = c(8, 10, 12)))
```

So the results are kind of useless for the examples used:

```
lapply(myList, function(sublist) eval(call(sublist$Function, sublist[["DataFrame"]])))
#> $Dataset1
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $Dataset2
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = structure(list(Col1 = c(2, 4, 6), Col2 = c(8, 10, 
#> 12)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)         Col2  
#>          -6            1  
#> 
#> 
#> Warning message:
#> In mean.default(list(Col1 = 1:3, Col2 = 4:6)) :
#>   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```